# Existence of Irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ of any given degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Question is to prove :

- Irreducibility of $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)- 1$ over  $\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\geq 1$
- Irreducibility of $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)+ 1$ over  $\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $n\neq 4$

Hint for first bullet is

> If the polynomial factors consider the value of the factors at $x=1,2,\dots,n$

For second bullet :

Suppose $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)-1$ is reducible we have:

$p(x)=q(x)r(x)$ with $\text {Max {degree of p(x), degree of r(x)}}<n$

Hint is suggesting me to use that $p(i)=-1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$

i.e., $q(i)r(i)=-1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$

i.e., $q(i)=-1; r(i)=1$ or $q(i)=1;r(i)=-1$  for all $1\leq i\leq n$

For second bullet :

Suppose $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)+1$ is reducible we have:

$p(x)=q(x)r(x)$ with $\text {Max {degree of p(x), degree of r(x)}}<n$

Hint is suggesting me to use that $p(i)=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$

i.e., $q(i)r(i)=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$

i.e., $q(i)=r(i)=1$ or $q(i)=r(i)=-1$  for all $1\leq i\leq n$

I am getting some vague ideas but could not bind them to prove this.

I would be thankful if some one can help me to clear this.

Thank you.

P.S : Please give "just hints". Do not write whole answer at once. This is a "request". Thank you :)

Edit : I have changed the title from

**Irreducibility of $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)\pm 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}$**

to

**Existence of Irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ of any given degree**

for two reasons :

- Irreducibility of $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)\pm 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ for any $n\geq 1$ implies Existence of Irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ of any given degree
- The title looks atractive

Comment: $p(i)=-1$ for the first bullet

Comment: why? I dont understand your point.... It would be $1$ :O Am i missing something?

Comment: Hint: How many zeros does $q(x)-r(x)$ have?

Comment: it will have $n$ zeros... so this has to be a polynomial of degree $n$ which contradicts that $q(x),r(x)$ have degree less than $n$ :) AMm i correct?

Comment: That's what I thought. It does leave the possibility $q(x)=r(x)$, so there's more to it.

Comment: I do not get your point :O

Comment: yes yes there is a possibility of $q(x)=r(x)$ In that case i have to shut my mouth :(

Comment: I am sorry I did not quite understand your question... do you mean $q(x)=r(x)$?

Comment: Interesting question, +1. What's the source? :)

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking about the first part there. Scratch that modulo four stuff.

Comment: @ccorn : Yes yes yes you are correct

Comment: @Prism : This is from Dummit Foote Abstract algebra..

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : So.. what should i do now :(

Comment: Need another trick. The first case is easy, as you can look at $q(x)+r(x)$, but the second? Thinking...

Comment: Are you proving the first bullet here? Then shouldn't it be q(x)+r(x) rather than "-"? In this case you can conclude that q(x)=-r(x), leading to a contradiction.

Comment: @benh : I am sorry for not being precise... I am trying to do both bullets at one shot (Hoping that it would work)... you are saying I should consider $q(x)+r(x)$ which have $n$ roots which is a contradiction..

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Sir, May day, May day!! a little progress... Please have a look at it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Extended hints as requested

Assume a factorization $p(x)=q(x)r(x)$.

---

**1:** $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)-1$

As you observed, in this first case you get $q(i)=-r(i)=\pm1$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, so $q(x)+r(x)$ has at least $n$ zeros. This is a problem, because the leading coefficients of $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ have the same sign.

---

**2:** $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-n)+1$

In the second case $q(i)=r(i)=\pm1$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, so we get that $q(x)-r(x)$ has at least $n$ zeros. As observed in the comments this leaves only the possibility $q(x)=r(x)$. Indeed, when $n=4$ we have
$$
p(x)=(x^2-5x+5)^2.
$$
Anyway, the remaining case is that $n=2k$, $q(x)=r(x)$, $k=\deg q(x)$. 
The factorization $p(x)=q(x)^2$ shows that $p(x)\ge0$ for all real numbers $x$. Estimate $p(2k-\dfrac12)$ when $k>2$.

Comment: Thank you for your interest... I am also thinking on that way... I am not getting any positive results... No hope :(

Comment: @Praphulla, Another idea came while dining with the family :-)

Comment: I did not get you... :)

Comment: Can you prove that $p(x)$ has a negative value at some point? In the second case, assuming $n=2k>4$. The case $n=2$ can be checked separately.

Comment: $p(1)=-1 <0$ so $p(x)$ have negative value at $1,2,\dots,n$

Comment: This is only needed for the second polynomial, when $p(i)=1$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Comment: I do not understand your question.. Am i missing something? do you want me to prove that $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)\dots (x-n)+1$ have negative value at some point?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $p(-1)<0$ :O so. how does this lead me to conlcusion :O

Comment: $p(-1)<0$ only for odd $n$, and these are already ruled out by $n=2k$. Besides, the way to the conclusion is already in the answer.

Comment: @ccorn Yes Yes you are correct $p(-1)<0$ only for odd $n$...

Comment: Jyrki has given $x=n-\frac{1}{2}$ to try: Look at $\cdots\frac{7}{2}\,\frac{5}{2}\,\frac{3}{2}\,\frac{1}{2}\,\frac{-1}{2}+1$.

Comment: @Praphulla: If you have the time, plot $p(x)$ for $n=4,6,8$. You will see, why I suggested $n-\dfrac12$ :-)

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I was so confused... What i have understood is $p(x)=q(x)r(x)$ and as we have $q(x)=r(x)$ we would have $p(x)=(q(x))^2$ which means $p(x)$ is always positive but you have written $p(x)^2\geq 0$ There i have got confused by noyt knowing why did you write that... Now as we are getting $p(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ we would end up with contradiction if we get some point where $p(x)$ takes negative value... and that is what i have to do

Comment: please edit $p(x)^2$ to $p(x)$ (If that is so)  That has confused me a lot :D

Comment: OOps. Corrected. Sorry about leading you astray to that extent.

Comment: Now every thing is perfect except for two points... how did you guess that $n-\frac{1}{2}$ gives negative value for $p$ :O and.. In answer for first bullet you said  "This is a problem, because the leading coefficients of q(x) and r(x) have the same sign." I do not understand this :O

Comment: As shown above, $x=n-\frac{1}{2}$ yields $p(x)<0$ because the product $(x-1)\cdots(x-n)$ has exactly one negative factor, and there are enough factors to make its absolute value greater than $1$, therefore the final $+1$ cannot change the sign any more.

Comment: I plotted $p(x)$, when $n=6$ and $n=8$. You do the same (Wolfram Alpha is your friend), and you see this deep valley there. My first thought actually was to prove that $p(x)$ has $n$ zeros, but I had forgotten about that while trying to make that "modulo 4" argument work.

Comment: As for the leading coefficients, well if $q(x)=-r(x)$, the leading coefficient of $q(x)r(x)$ must be negative. But $p(x)$ has positive leading coefficient.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : oh yes... I have seen it just now.... Thank you so much for your wonderful support (as always) :)

Comment: @ccorn : I am so thankful for your wonderful support :) Please join in the club of people in MSE helping me from day 1... :D Thank you so much once again!