# Proving certain polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, factoring

Show that the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n)-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. [hint: if the polynomial factors consider the values of the factors at $x = 1,2,3....,n$.

Show that the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n)+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ $\forall n \geq 1, n \neq 4$.

I've been running around in circles on this one for awhile now and can't seem to get anywhere! Some insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks yall!

Comment: @lulu I think the referenced Q does not consider the $+1$ variant.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  [The question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624852/existence-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-mathbbz-of-any-given-degree) cited as a duplicate for that one does

Comment: @lulu Voting with different duplicates will show all of them.

Comment: @egreg  Didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: @lulu I'm not sure who can, but I see also an “edit” link below the list of duplicates. It's possibly a “gold badge privilege”.

Comment: @egreg  Next time it comes up, I'll give it a try.