# $(2n)!+1$ is not a perfect square for $n > 2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

It seems to me that it may be true that $(2n)!+1$ is not a perfect square for $n>2$. We can see that if $n=2$, then $4!+1=25=5^2$. But it seems that for all the small numbers of $n$ that I can try on my computer, there is no integer square root for $n>2$. I was surprised to not find much about this after googling and searching this site. Maybe I missed something.

If this statement were true, it would help with a question from ring theory that I am working on. I am working on a proof/counterexample but I thought I would ask the community what they thought about this.

Comment: It is an open problem called  Brocard's problem: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem

Comment: @Nulhomologous: Your comment is probably the best possible answer to the question; care to write it as one?

Comment: [$n!+1$ being a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/n1-being-a-perfect-square)

Comment: @Nulhomologous thanks, i knew I had missed something. So this would be a the case for even integers $n$.

Comment: What exactly is the ring-theory problem you want to solve ?

Comment: @Peter part 2 of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624852/existence-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-mathbbz-of-any-given-degree. If we can show that $(2n)!+1$ has no sqaure root in $\mathbb{Z}$ then it is a nice direct proof.

Comment: The conjecture has been verified upto very large $n$. Almost surely, the list of solutions $4,5,7$ is complete. This situation is quite common in mathematics. Many important results depend on the (generalized) Riemann hypothesis. Here we have a similar case.