# Specific detail in the irreducibility of $(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n)-1$ in the integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am studying the [seemingly official accepted answer to this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624852/existence-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-mathbbz-of-any-given-degree).  Here is a screen shot of the answer.

> [image]

If we assume that $p(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, then we can assume a factorization, $p(x)=q(x)r(x)$, of $p(x)$ into two non-units. Consequently, the degree of both $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ must be greater than zero.

I understand that $q(i)=-r(i)$ for $i = 1,2,...,n$ implies that $q(x)+r(x)$ has at least $n$ roots. I also understand that since $p(x)$ is monic then so are $r(x)$ and $q(x)$, and $p(x)$ is has a positive coefficient in front of $x^n$, so the coefficients of the largest power of $r(x)$ and $q(x)$ must have the same sign. But I am still not seeing how this implies a contradiction.

To me it seems like the argument could work like this: because $q(x)+r(x)$ has at least $n$ zeros, that means $deg(q(x)+r(x)) \ge n$. This means that either $q(x)$ or $r(x)$ has degree greater than or equal to $n$. But by the properties of multiplication of monic polynomials we must have that the degree of $q(x)$ and $r(x)$ be strictly less than $n$.

Comment: This is the argument, but then you have to argue why $q+r\neq 0$, and this is where the sign thing comes up.

Comment: OK yes I see that since the degree of $q,r$ is greater than zero with both the same sign we could not have $q+r=0$.

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed the correct argument; the sign issue as stated is only to demonstrate that $q+r$ is not the zero polynomial.